# Mongoose aggression with sum and count

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection with the following data.

```
{
  "_id": "a123",
  "amount":250,
  "products": [
    {
      "user_id": "a321",
      "price": 230
    },
    {
      "user_id": "a323",
      "price": 30
    }
  ],
  "services": [
    {
      "name": "sr 1",
      "price": 230
    },
    {
      "name": "sr 2",
      "price": 250
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id": "a124",
  "amount":250,
  "products": [
    {
      "user_id": "a321",
      "price": 230
    },
    {
      "user_id": "a323",
      "price": 30
    }
  ],
  "services": [
    {
      "name": "sr 1",
      "price": 230
    },
    {
      "name": "sr 2",
      "price": 250
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to perform an aggregation operation `based on the author id`. so that I will get the following.

```
 Total Services, Total Products, Products Price, Serice Price
```

**Total Service: Total price of each service for the `user_id a321`**
**Total Products: Total price of each product for the `user_id a321`**
**Services: No of services (which will be the length of the array) for the `user_id a321`**
**Products: No of products for the `user_id a321`**
Expected Output

```
{
  "user_id": "a321",
  "totalService": 960,
  "totalProducts": 460,
  "Services": 4,
  "Products": 2,
  "Total": 500
}
```

How to find the above details by using mongo aggregation from the above-mentioned collection.

Comment: How are you arriving to the numbers in `Expected output` based on your collection?

Comment: can you explain the meaning of each documents, for example if the "same" service is in 2 different documents do you count it twice or once?,  what is a "book"? etc

Comment: @TomSlabbaert have look at the question. I have updated the question and explained the same as you requested